# How do I convert those columns to rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

[image]

after convert, it should be

```
month   1 2    3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12   
planqty 0 0 6230 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0    
actqty  0 0 2631 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0
```

I will be so appreciated if you can help.

Comment: You'll want to look up pivoting

Comment: I know, but  I can't convert 'planqty' and 'actqty' to the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `APPLY` (i.e. `CROSS APPLY`) in order to convert *columns* to *row* wise.

```
select 
       qtynames as Month,
       max(case when dt = '01' then qty end) [01],
       max(case when dt = '02' then qty end) [02], 
       max(case when dt = '03' then qty end) [03],...
from table t cross apply (
    values ('month', dt, 'planqty', planqty), ('month', dt, 'actqty', actqty)
)a(mnames, dates, qtynames, qty)
group by qtynames
```